# Android intent for opening twitter reply

Tags: android, android-intent, twitter, android-twitter

From my app I am trying to open twitter app so that the first screen is automatic reply to a tweet. I found the web intent for doing so: https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?in_reply_to=

I found a android intent for opening a tweet: twitter://status?status_id=

But I cannot find android intent for reply or retweet.

Can anyone help please?

Comment: The web intent will launch twitter app, if it is installed. Why do you search twitter scheme intent?

Comment: Yes it will launch it but not directly to reply or retweet like it does on the web. That is the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I think they expect you to use Fabric https://docs.fabric.io/android/twitter/compose-tweets.html which was built by twitter for mobile app development.

Comment: But I don't want to use it in app I just want to open twitter app or browser to that specific point :/ So you are telling me that that is not possible?

Comment: Fabric opens the Twitter app if it is installed